# About encode/decode in ftplib in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a request to handle with filename list on ftp server. But filename includes Asian character and other unknown characters.  So I need to judge which filename can be decoded by gb2312, which can be decoded by iso-8859-1. That means if the filename list cannot be gotten using gb2312, then use iso-88591-1 to get. So I don't know how to write code in the following function which is in ftplib

```
def retrlines(self, cmd, callback = None):
    """Retrieve data in line mode.  A new port is created for you.

    Args:
      cmd: A RETR, LIST, NLST, or MLSD command.
      callback: An optional single parameter callable that is called
                for each line with the trailing CRLF stripped.
                [default: print_line()]

    Returns:
      The response code.
    """
    if callback is None: callback = print_line
    resp = self.sendcmd('TYPE A')
##################I need to update here############################
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
             conn.makefile('r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as fp:
###################################################################
        while 1:

            line = fp.readline()
            print(line)

            if self.debugging > 2: print('*retr*', repr(line))
            if not line:
                break
            if line[-2:] == CRLF:
                line = line[:-2]
            elif line[-1:] == '\n':
                line = line[:-1]
            callback(line)
    return self.voidresp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including much of the code, so it's hard to tell exactly what is going on. But as a general rule, if the data you are interacting with isn't consistent in it's usage of encodings, you will have to interact with it in binary mode.

So try not passing in an encoding at all. Hopefully that will give you bytes data back, and you can then encode/decode according to the needs of each file.